# Reference error in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have recently updated to IOS 6. I had project which worked fine for iOS 4.3, now when I try to build for device it is showing lot of reference error.

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
```

Actually I don't have all source code, I have been using .a's also for some classes, for that classes .a's also I have asked to built with Xcode 4.5.1 (for device) and tried with that, still no use. If I use the simulator it is working fine, for device built problem showed up. 
I have googled for any solution, found some its not helping my problem.
Any one faced like this after updated to iOS 6. How to get rid of it.

Waiting for your helps. thanks.

Comment: Search here for `armv7s symbols` and you'll find plenty of existing questions on this topic.

Comment: It is because those .a files are not built for armv7s architecture. You need to build it for armv7 by pointing to iOS device instead of simulator. The replace your .a file in project with this one and try again.

Comment: @ACB I have asked twice to check that, they are saying its built with Xcode 4.5 only, to build espescially for armv7 do we need to do anything in Xcode?

Comment: Yes, you do, and all the answers on stack overflow already tell you how...so try doing a search.

Comment: Ask them to check if the architecture in Xcode build settings. Is it pointing to armv7s? I have faced similar issue and it always worked in simulator but not in device. I got a new one generated and that fixed the issue. So I am sure that it is an issue with that settings itself

Comment: @ACB thanks man, I will ask them again to check.

Comment: @Newbee You should add a compiler flag which builds for ARMv6 as well. In Xcode, search for it (dunno where it is off the top of my head), and add `-arch armv6` both to the compiler and linker flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick solution, you can check `Build Active Architecture Only` on each of the Project configurations (Debug, Release and Deployment) and in the Build Settings of the Target. This will allow you to build the project.

**Note**: *This is only a temporary solution.You have indeed to update the library or framework you are using to the latest version which support armv7s(Architecture for iPhone5).*

Comment: Ya it is succeeded now. Can you please tell me, what is happening?

Comment: Any problem if I continue like this?

Comment: The '.a' file is a library file. This is precompiled code. The armv7s architecture is introduced in iPhone5. So when the library is compiled the creator doesn't add such an architecture in the valid architectures of the library project(The architecture is not there at that time). In the new XCode with iOS6 support, when we are compiling our source code with this library, these xcode needs armv7s symbols too in the library. But its not there. Thats why it's showing error. By checking the 'Build Active Architecture Only' we are telling the compiler that, just build available architecture only.

Comment: You can use it for the time being in development. But you can't upload the binary to App Store with the 'Build Active Architecture Only' checked. So as early as possible you should update the library.